# Filtering a NSArray containing objects with a NSDate field with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nspredicate

I have an array of objects, with each object containing a field called date.  I want to create a subset of this array using `NSPredicate` where I pull only those objects that fall within a certain date range.  Here's the code I am using:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date =< %@)", startDate, endDate];
_daysArray = [_cachedDaysArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

The problem I am having is when `startDate` and `endDate` are the same day, but different times.  Here's the variables view in the XCode debugger

[image]

As you can see, I have an object in the array that has a `date` field equal to `startDate`, but you can also see that `_daysArray` contains no elements after the filter is executed.

This works fine when the dates are not the same day.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT #1**

Here's the `po` of the `predicate` variable as requested by commenter:

```
(lldb) po predicate
date >= CAST(406616400.676014, "NSDate") AND date <= CAST(406702799.677098, "NSDate")
(lldb)
```

**EDIT #2**

```
(lldb) po [[_cachedDaysArray firstObject] date]
2013-11-18 05:00:00 +0000
(lldb)
```

**EDIT #3**

Martin R. got me on the right track with his comment on how `startDate` was being calculated.  Now that I have changed that, it's working.  I am using a method to calculate `startDate`.  Previously, I was using `NSUIntegerMax` to indicate the components, now I am breaking them out specifically:

```
-(NSDate *)pastDate:(NSInteger)daysPast
{
    // Get the appropriate calendar
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *startComponents = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [startComponents setHour: 00];
    [startComponents setMinute: 00];
    [startComponents setSecond: 00];
    startComponents.day = startComponents.day - daysPast;

    return [calendar dateFromComponents:startComponents];
}
```

Comment: You could try converting to NSTimeInterval. It would could be a more efficient check anyways than comparing objects.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how would I check a NSDate value in a predicate against a NSTimeInterval value?

Comment: Can you print predicate with "po" in console before you filter ? Also please print that: "po [[_cachedDaysArray firstObject] date]" to see if your object desponds correctly to predicate getter.

Comment: Can you try removing a brackets in predicate and check if that works ?

Comment: If not paste a bit more code around so we can check what are you doing there - maybe you overwrite this array or something strange like that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the output of the predicate

```
date >= CAST(406616400.676014, "NSDate") AND date <= CAST(406702799.677098, "NSDate")
```

one can see that `startDate` is **not** exactly "2013-11-20 05:00:00 +0000" (UTC) or 
"2013-11-20 00:00:00" (EST) but **0.676014 seconds later**.
Therefore, if the date of the object in `_cachedDaysArray` falls *exactly* on
midnight of 2013-11-20, it does *not* match the predicate.

It seems that the calculation of `startDate` and `endDate` does not
exactly what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for this observation.  I will look into this right now.

Comment: @CMVR: If you show the code how start/endDate are calculated then a more specific answer might be possible.

Comment: You got me on the right path.  It was how I was calculating the start and end dates.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your dates to do not include time, before you pass it to your predicate.
Try this:

```
-(NSDate*)dateNoTime:(NSDate*)myDate
{

NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate: myDate];
return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comp];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I am doing this for the `date` field in the object to get the time to be midnight.  I am also doing this for `startDate` and `endDate` to get the times right.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(TRDay *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return evaluatedObject.date.timeIntervalSince1970 >= startDate.timeIntervalSince1970 && evaluatedObject.date.timeIntervalSince1970 <= endDate.timeIntervalSince1970;
}];
```

Comment: I don't have a `dates` array, it is a field on an object in an array.  Correct me if I am wrong, but `valueForKeyPath` uses a variable name to pull the values out of the array.  I do not have any variable named `timeIntervalSince1970` in my class.  That is a method on NSDate.  Again, please correct me if I am wrong, but I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Yeah misunderstood try that.

Comment: then something must be wrong with your dates. That's basically a double comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like that:

```
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components3 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components3 setYear:2013];
[components3 setMonth:11];
[components3 setDay:20];
NSDate *startDate = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:components3];

[components3 setHour:23];
[components3 setMinute:59];
[components3 setSecond:59];

NSDate *endDate = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:components3];
[gregorianCalendar release];

NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[startDate] forKeys:@[@"date"]];
NSArray* mainArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dict, nil];

NSPredicate* pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date =< %@)", startDate, endDate];
NSArray* filteredArray = [mainArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

And it works as expected. Basically it means you have error somewhere else.

Comment: Looks like the difference is that I am using `NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];` and you are pulling objects into a dictionary for some reason.  Don't know why...